# The query in the jrxml file does not work

Tags: query-string

I am trying to create reports using JasperReports, but anytime i run the scrip it always reurns an error stating that Invalid content was found starting with element 'queryString', I'm guessing i did not arrange the query in the queryString element

here is the jrxml code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE jasperReport PUBLIC "//JasperReports//DTD Report Design//EN"
"http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/dtds/jasperreport.dtd">
<jasperReport name="staff">


<field name="staffId" class="java.lang.String"/>
<field name="firstName" class="java.lang.String"/>
<field name="lastName" class="java.lang.String"/>
<field name="email" class="java.lang.String"/>
<field name="password" class="java.lang.String"/>

<queryString><![CDATA[select * from staff]]>
</queryString>


<pageHeader>
<band height="30">
<staticText>
<reportElement x="0" y="0" width="69" height="24"/>
<textElement verticalAlignment="Bottom"/>
<text>
<![CDATA[Staff ID: ]]>
</text>
</staticText>
<staticText>
<reportElement x="140" y="0" width="69" height="24"/>
<text>
<![CDATA[First Name: ]]>
</text>
</staticText>
<staticText>
<reportElement x="280" y="0" width="69" height="24"/>
<text>
<![CDATA[Last Name: ]]>
</text>
</staticText>
<staticText>
<reportElement x="420" y="0" width="69" height="24"/>
<text>
<![CDATA[Email: ]]>
</text>
</staticText>
<staticText>
<reportElement x="420" y="0" width="69" height="24"/>
<text>
<![CDATA[Password: ]]>
</text>
</staticText>
</band>
</pageHeader>


<detail>
<band height="30">
<textField>
<reportElement x="0" y="0" width="69" height="24"/>
<textFieldExpression class="java.lang.String">
<![CDATA[$F{staffId}]]>
</textFieldExpression>
</textField>
<textField>
<reportElement x="140" y="0" width="69" height="24"/>
<textFieldExpression class="java.lang.String">
<![CDATA[$F{firstName}]]>
</textFieldExpression>
</textField>
<textField>
<reportElement x="280" y="0" width="69" height="24"/>
<textFieldExpression class="java.lang.String">
<![CDATA[$F{lastName}]]>
</textFieldExpression>
</textField>
<textField>
<reportElement x="420" y="0" width="69" height="24"/>
<textFieldExpression class="java.lang.String">
<![CDATA[$F{email}]]>
</textFieldExpression>
</textField>
<textField>
<reportElement x="420" y="0" width="69" height="24"/>
<textFieldExpression class="java.lang.String">
<![CDATA[$F{password}]]>
</textFieldExpression>
</textField>
</band>
</detail>
</jasperReport>
```

I then removed the Stringquery elemnt and the JasperViewer opend but had no content.

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look [Here](http://mssqlwithiireports.blogspot.in/2012/11/simle-java-program-to-generate-report.html)

I created jrxml file with the help of ireports designer 4.8 and query is part of this file and same report file work with java code as well .